# Calculating interpolating polynomial with limited number of divisions

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I have to calculate the error of aproximations of $f(x)=-x^5$ by two interpolating polynomials - one of degree 2 based on knots $x_0=-2$, $x_1=0$,  $x_2=2$ and another one based on knots $x_0=-2$, $x_1=0$,  $x_2=2$, $x_3=-3$ , $x_4=3$ , $x_5=-4$ , $x_6=4$. The catch is I can only use division 4 times in my calculations for the entire problem. So the Newton form is out of the question. That leaves me with the Lagrange form. My intuition says that because $f(x)$ is odd, the values of $l_i$ will act in similar fashion but I'm not sure how to prove it. If that's the case though for the second polynomial I'd only have to calculate the values for 4 elements which would fit in the division limit but I'd still have to use divisions to calculate the first polynomial. I'd be grateful for any ideas on how to proceed from here

Comment: Use [Neville's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm) for the 7 nodes. Yes, the parity tells you that you only need to compute half of the pyramid. The error for the $7$ node interpolation is obtained at the end, while the error for the $3$ point interpolation is an intermediate value in the computation.

Comment: But if I use this algorithm even on the half of the pyamid, doesn't it still take like 12 divisions to perform the computations ?

Comment: True. But, since the degree of $f$ is $4$, and the interpolation polynomial is unique, when you use more than $5$ nodes, you should get $f$. Therefore, the error in the case of the $7$ different nodes doesn't need to be computed.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Why doesn't the error of an unique interpolation has to be calculated? Does uniquness imply that the error is 0? Is there a theorem or something I could look up on that?

Comment: Yes, the [uniqueness of the interpolating polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Uniqueness_of_the_interpolating_polynomial). That implies that the error for the case of $7$ different nodes is necessarily zero for $f(x)=-x^4$.

Comment: Oh that's extremly helpful then. Also I seem to have made a type - $f(x)$  is actually &-x^5& but it still doesnt change the solution

Comment: Yes, it could have even be $-x^6$.

Comment: If you reduce the whole sum to the common denominator, you can do with a single division !

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about the uniqueness thing. Maybe I just didn't fully understand the definition but doesn't the interpolating polynomial only have to be equal to $f$ only on $f_i$ (the $y$ values of the points)? Or does uniquness mean the polynomial has values equal to $f$ for every $x$ th domain of th function?

Answer (score 1):

$$y_0\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)}+y_1\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_2)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2)}+y_2\frac{(x-x_0)(x-x_1)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)}=$$

$$\frac{y_0(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x_2-x_1)+y_1(x-x_0)(x-x_2)(x_0-x_2)+y_2(x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x_1-x_0)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_1-x_2)(x_2-x_0)}.$$

A single division is enough. (Of course this is a sillily inefficient approach for larger $n$, but it fits with the problem statement.)